# Retrieve specific value if set, or general if not

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to write a query which will import some data from table. Table structure is like:

- Item_ID
- Plant
- Price

I have second table with

- Item_ID
- Plant

Second table is a key, and I have to match rows from first table to get valid price. Seems to be easy, however:
In first table column plant might determinate specific plant, or have value 'ALL'. What I want to do is retrieve price for given plant, if it is set, or get price for value 'ALL' if there is no row for given plant. In other words:

```
If first.Plant = second.Plant
  return price
Else If first.Plant = 'ALL'
  return price
Else
  return NULL
```

I can't use simple `ON first.Plant = second.Plant OR first.Plant = 'ALL'`, because there might be two rows: one for given plant and second for rest with value 'ALL'. I need to return only first price in that case. E.g.

```
Item_ID  | Plant  | Price 
  2      |   M1   |  10,0
  2      |  All   |  12,0
  1      |  All   |  9,0
```

In that case for Item_ID = 2 and Plant = M1 **the only** valid price = 10, but for Item_ID = 2 and Plant = M2 price =  12, and for any Item_ID = 1 price = 9

I hope You understood something after my explanation ;)

Comment: Please provide your source data, ideally as a sql `create table ... insert ...` statement

Comment: Where do u get m2 from, what drives this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ROW_Number and a Common Table Expression you can ensure that ROW_NUMBER is partitioned by Item_ID and Plant and ordered such that if there are two rows then 'All' is second. You then simple select the rows with a row number = 1:

***Setup***

```
CREATE TABLE #Price
(
    Item_ID int,
    Plant Varchar(20),
    Price Decimal(6,2)
)

CREATE TABLE #Plant
(
    Item_ID int,
    Plant VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Price
VALUES  (2,  'M1', 10.0),
        (2, 'All', 12.0),
        (1, 'All', 9.0)

INSERT INTO #Plant
VALUES (2,  'M1'),
        (2, 'M2'),
        (1, 'M1'),
        (1, 'M2')
```

Here's the query for SQL Server >= 2012

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT PL.Item_ID, PL.Plant, PR.PRice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pl.Item_ID, Pl.Plant ORDER BY IIF(PR.Plant = 'All', 1, 0)) AS RN
    FROM #Plant PL
    INNER JOIN #Price PR
        ON PL.Item_Id = PR.Item_Id AND  (PL.Plant = PR.Plant OR PR.Plant = 'ALL')
)
SELECT Item_Id, Plant, Price
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

And here's a version using CASE which will work for all SQL Server >= 2008 R2

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT PL.Item_ID, PL.Plant, PR.PRice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pl.Item_ID, Pl.Plant ORDER BY CASE WHEN PR.Plant = 'All' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS RN
    FROM #Plant PL
    INNER JOIN #Price PR
        ON PL.Item_Id = PR.Item_Id AND  (PL.Plant = PR.Plant OR PR.Plant = 'ALL')
)
SELECT Item_Id, Plant, Price
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```